# Octave log(a) vs log a

Tags: function, command, octave

In octave what is the difference between log(a) and log a?

```
>>a
a =

   1   2

>>log(a)
ans =

   0.00000   0.69315

>>log a
ans =  4.5747
```

Comment: `log a` doesn't work in [GNU Octave 3.8](http://mxeoctave.osuv.de/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second example, Octave is interpreting `'a'` as a char, converting `'a'` to its ASCII representation (97) and then getting the natural logarithm.

```
log(97) = 4.5747
```

In general you have two ways to call functions: as a function or as a command. E.g.

```
save('test.txt')
save test.txt
```

When a function is used as a command, it assumes the input is a string.

Anyway newer version of Matlab and Octave have an error check for character input (there is little reason to compute the logarithm of the ASCII equivalent of a character).